react vite cannot read environment variable from vscode launch.json
I am learning react vite and would like to try passing environment variables from different places. I can successfully set and use environment variable in .env and in package.json scripts. However, if I set in the launch.json file, I could not read the environment variable in vite code.
Here is my launch.json look like
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "env": {
        "VITE_TEST": "12345"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Then I try to access it in my vite code as
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_TEST)
However, I get undefined.
Can anyone please help? Thank you
